# ERRO "do not have a property of the name return"

Tags: java, web-service, soap

Olá, estou tentando implementar um WebService e estou tendo problema na resposta. Utilizei o SoapUi e está funcionando. Estou na etapa de implementar o cliente do WebService na aplicação.
Quando faço a requisição, o erro de resposta aparece "[class] do not have a property of the name return"

Segue o código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XmlDoc doc = null;

    try {
        List<String> documento = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Ceser\\Desktop\\teste.xml"));

        WebService1 service = new WebService1();
        WebService1Soap soap = service.getWebService1Soap();

        soap.inserirPedido(2, (XmlDoc) documento);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Requisição:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "iTipo", "xmlDoc" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "inserirPedido")
public class InserirPedido {

protected int iTipo;
protected InserirPedido.XmlDoc xmlDoc;

public int getITipo() {
    return iTipo;
}

public void setITipo(int value) {
    this.iTipo = value;
}

public InserirPedido.XmlDoc getXmlDoc() {
    return xmlDoc;
}

public void setXmlDoc(InserirPedido.XmlDoc value) {
    this.xmlDoc = value;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "content" })
public static class XmlDoc {

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;

    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

}
```

}

Resposta:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "inserirPedidoResponse")
public class InserirPedidoResponse {



}
```

EXCEPTION:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class br.com.caelum.estoquews.cliente.InserirPedidoResponse do not have a property of the name return
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.buildResponseBuilder(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.initStubHandlers(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
>       at br.com.caelum.estoquews.cliente.WebService1.getWebService1Soap(WebService1.java:72)
>       at br.com.caelum.estoquews.cliente.TesteWebService.main(TesteWebService.java:23)
>   Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: return is not a valid property on class br.com.caelum.estoquews.cliente.InserirPedidoResponse
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(Unknown Source)
>       ... 17 more